# Magento 2 - How to use admin panel email template in my custom module?

Tags: email, custom, email-templates, magento2.2.2

I have created the custom module for customer registration request including an email function also.
email function is working fine.

I have customized the email template using Marketing -> Communication ->Newsletter Template -> Add New Template.

When customer registration request the email template is not getting from the customized one.its getting from the module.

What i want to do to use the customized email template?

file -> **email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template id="registration_request_template" label="Customer Registration Request" file="registration_request.html" type="html" module="E25media_CustomerRegistration" area="frontend"/>
```

Controller email

```
$full_name = $first_name." ".$last_name;
        $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $templateVars = array(
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                    'full_name' => $full_name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    'company' => $company,
                    'position' => $position,
                    'vessel' => $vessel
                );
        $from = array('email' => $email, 'name' => $full_name);
        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $to = array('mujahidhaseem@gmail.com');
        $to = $this->getCustomerSupportEmail();
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('registration_request_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @AnshuMishra i have updated the email xml and controller email section

Answer (score 0):

You need to add file from the file structure. Please add the template in view-> frontend->email folder and then modify the email_template.xml

File->email_template.xml

```
    <template id="registration_request_template" label="Email Form" file="registration_request_template.html" type="html" module="companyname_modulename" area="frontend"/>
```

Please clear cache and run indexing and check!
Hope it helps!

Comment: Have u defined it in email_template.xml because the code you shared doenst have it

Answer (score 0):

You have provided static email template id in your code as follows:

```
setTemplateIdentifier('registration_request_template')
```

instead of static email id, you have can create an option in admin to select the email template, something as follows:
**Code in your module's etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
------

<section id="custom_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    -----
    <group id="custom_fields_masks" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1">
        <label>Custom label</label>
        <field id="custom_email_template" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
            <label>Email Template</label>
            <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
        </field>
    </group>
    -------
```

Then you can call the template id using the following code:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            <field path>,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            <store_id>
        );
```

All the above codes are sample you need to modify according to your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your answer.can you please explain little bit more regarding this?if possible with some sample codes

Comment: @Mujahidh basically, that whole point is that, you need to provide the email template id of the template that you have created in admin in the code setTemplateIdentifier('registration_request_template')